# How to keep track of users (connections) in a WebSocket Chat application

Tags: ruby, websocket, eventmachine

I'm using the `em-websocket` (Ruby EventMachine) gem to serve up a WebSocket chat application. I was able to get a demo app working pretty easy ([based on this gist](https://gist.github.com/1308112)). Now I would like to go a little more advanced. Currently, the only functionality is to post a message to the chatroom, but it is not show who sent the message (because I don't know how to keep track of this information).

I'm assuming the way to do this is to send JSON back and forth with some sort of ID, but where does this ID come from? Is there some sort of reusable ID that is unique to each connection that identifies the user?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am new to working with WebSockets.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a basic chat app using em-websocket.  You can see the code here:

https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/websocket-chat/blob/master/rws1/server.rb

The em-websocket gem creates a web socket object to represent each connection.  I made my own Client class which holds a user name and a reference to the websocket object.

Feel free to ask me questions about that code.

Comment: I did not use json and I don't think you need to either, at least for now.

Comment: This is pretty awesome. I have one question. If you have the client's  name and therefore the corresponding websocket object, how do you send a message over that specific websocket?

Comment: Just do `websocket.send message` where `websocket` is a web socket object and `message` is a string.  The `send` method is provided by em-websocket.

Comment: Ok, I also noticed you called `websocket.request["Query"]["name"]` in the `addClient` method. What does this get and where can you find methods that can be called on the websocket object? Also you call `send(command, websocket, data)` in `handle_message` which seems different from `websocket.send`

Comment: Actually it needs to be "query" instead of "Query" to work with the latest version of em-websocket.  This gets the name request by the client, which is included in the query string of the url of the websocket, "GET /chatroom?name=David" is the first line of the request from the client.   Documentation of em-websocket is here:  https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket   I don't know if they have a good API listing of all the commands, sometimes I poke around in the source code or use `websocket.methods.inspect`.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Have you extended this app to allow for group chatting? as in all the members of a group can see the message sent by all other members in the group?

Comment: Yes, except it's just one group consisting of everyone connected to the server.